# Expected Value with Parameter p

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

The random variable X has the following probability distribution:

P[X=-1]= (1-p)/2

P[X=0]= 1/2

P[X=1]= p/2

The parameter p satisfies the inequality $0 < p < 1$.

Find the expected value and variance of X.

Do I need to try and solve for p before calculating? I have already multiplied the values for X by their probabilities and I ended up with E[X]=(-1/2)+p. Can anyone confirm if this is correct?

Comment: $p$ is a parameter, so you do not solve for $p$

Comment: yes this is correct. Since $p$ is bounded, $\mathbf{E}X$ will be bounded too.

Comment: Ok, next I need to calculate the variance, and I have attempted under the assumption that the EX was (1/2)+p. The answer isn't "pretty", but that should be expected since I don't have a known value for p, right?

Comment: I get $p-0.5$, hm.. $E[X] = \sum P_i X_i$ or?

Comment: Ok, I see my error now. I shouldn't have multiplied the denominator by -1, must've been working too quickly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathbb{E}X=\frac{1-p}{2}\times\left(-1\right)+\frac{1}{2}\times0+\frac{p}{2}\times1=\dots$$

$$\mathbb{E}X^{2}=\frac{1-p}{2}\times\left(-1\right)^{2}+\frac{1}{2}\times0^{2}+\frac{p}{2}\times1^{2}=\dots$$

$$\text{Var}X=\mathbb{E}X^{2}-\left(\mathbb{E}X\right)^{2}=\dots$$

Help yourself.

Your original solution (*before your edit*) $\mathbb{E}X=\frac{1}{2}+p$ is **not** correct.

Comment: Glad to read that.

Comment: That is how I set up EX, so the first term becomes (-1+p)/-2 which then becomes (1+p)/2, no?

Comment: The first term becomes $(-1+p)/2$. Adding this term to $p/2$ gives $p-\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

E(X) is correct. And the variance is $Var(X)=E(X^2)-\left[ E(X) \right] ^2$.

Comment: [(1/2)+p]^2 is [E(X)]^2, but I'm having trouble coming up with E(X^2). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $E(X^2)=\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i^2 \cdot f(x_i)$ And E(X) should be $p-1/2$